# How can I extend the chimney insulation shield before adding cellulose?

Tags: insulation, attic, chimney

I'm adding 12 inches on blown cellulose on top of the existing fiberglass. There is a shield around the chimmney duct but it is not long enough, see:

[image]

The cellulose will enter in contact with the hot chimney duct.

Should I do something about it? The 2 contractors I asked for submission before going DIY clearly wouldn't have done anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can place rockwool around the chimney flue, it is a non combustible insulation.

Comment: Thanks! Turns out I found the perfect product: https://www.renodepot.com/en/supervent-2-in-x-12-in-x-48-in-universal-mineral-wool-insulation-shielding-jusi-30738344